# Need assistance customizing jQuery horizontal menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

I have downloaded this cool menu to use in my first webesite

http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/jquery-responsive-dropdown-menu
The code could be downloaded when you press download source from the link

I need your kind assistance with two points:

**point1:** the menu comes under the other elements in the page, what command can I add to the menu code to force the menu to be on top of any element in the page?

**point2:** I need to add setting button with drop down options to the right edge of the menu that will contain: profile, setting and logout
I can have it next to other buttons but I need it to the very right of the menu

```
<li><a href='#'><span>Settings</span></a> 
<ul>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Profile</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Setting</span></a></li>
     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Logout</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you post the sample code?

Comment: You will want to set the `z-index` css property of the entire menu to something high so as to make it appear above other elements.  Then look at using `float:right` css property of the settings.

Comment: I edited the post with the CSS code and it could be found in this link http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/jquery-responsive-dropdown-menu  when you press download source ... thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't manage to edit this nav-bar template and eventually I gave up,  I made the following and the result is quite good, as to be said satisfying me

**Workaround:**

1. I used bootstrap navbar
2. I used http://bootstrap-live-customizer.com/ to customize the colors
3. I extracted the .css file from the site and added it after bootstrap
   in the header

The nav-bar is less attractive but as a trade-off with functionality I kept it this way

Thanks to all who answered and provided help, appreciate it all

Answer (score 0):

For **Point 1**:

You need to set the `z-index` a higher value than the other elements in your page, that obstructs the menu.

```
.submenu {z-index: 99999;}
```

For **Point 2**:

Give a `float: right;` for the `<li>` which holds the two settings link, or give a class `last` and assign the CSS:

```
li.last {float: right;}
```

```
<li class="last">
  <!-- The last menu -->
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you Praveen, but none of these worked  ----- for point 1, I added z-index to 99999 in all the items in the menu and added z-index to 10 to all other elements in the page still I have the drop down menu under the contents  ---- for point 2: it still in the same place at the end of the other buttons to the left ... any idea ?  thank you again

Comment: @Nsh Try giving a `width: 100%` for the parent of the `<li class="last">`, which might solve the problem. It would be really nice if you can make a fiddle to replicate the **point 1**.

Comment: z-index only works if you have that element's position set to absolute, fixed or relative. (or maybe flex, too. Not sure about flex). Without seeing your CSS, I can't tell if that's the problem or not.

Comment: @RaphaeldiSanto I assume, being the floating dropdown menu, it should be positioned absolute (or relative in some cases).

Comment: Well, the fact that it's a drop down menu has no bearing on whether it should be position: absolute or position: relative. Or even position: fixed. That will be determined by how you want it to display in the page. Depending on the rest of your layout and the other CSS, it could be any one of those three.

Comment: The CSS file could be found in the link .. when you open it there is download source and you can have it .. I am using it as is .. I didnt dare to change it not to ruin it  ------- for point 1 the position: absolute; for all the options in the menu -- for point 2 adding the width 100% ruined the menu totally its now 5 lines and as block not inline but extending to full page

Comment: @PraveenKumar I think op is asking about dom structure and not z-index. If he shows us the page code it can be easily fixed. Probably he is declaring the menu at the bottom of the page and not on top!

Comment: Okay, construct whatever you have and make it live somewhere, like [plunker](http://plnkr.co/).

Comment: I edited the post with the CSS code and it could be found in this link cssmenumaker.com/menu/jquery-responsive-dropdown-menu when you press download source ... thank you